# Unable to click on Button using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to click on this button to go to the next page, but for some reason, I'm unable to. I tried xpath, css, and class selectors as well as the data-trekkie-id attribute, but nothing I have tried worked. Any help? Code below:

```
<div class="step__footer" data-step-footer="">
    <button name="button" type="submit" class="step__footer__continue-btn btn " data-trekkie-id="continue_to_shipping_method_button" aria-busy="false">
        <span class="btn__content">
            Continue to shipping method
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: any error or exception when you click to it?

Comment: That isn't code; that's html, and it's only half of the equation.  Show us the _code_.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* to invoke `click()` method on the button with text as **Continue to shipping method** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.step__footer__continue-btn.btn[data-trekkie-id='continue_to_shipping_method_button']>span.btn__content"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='step__footer__continue-btn btn' and @data-trekkie-id='continue_to_shipping_method_button']/span[@class='btn__content']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(local-name(), 'button') and contains(@class, 'step__footer__continue-btn')]").click()
```